# Qt and mkpasswd MD5 hashes difference

Tags: c++, bash, qt

1. In Qt5 i have a code with QCryptographicHash:

   ```
   QString pass = "test";
   QString hash = QString(QCryptographicHash::hash(pass.toLatin1(),QCryptographicHash::Md5).toHex());
   qDebug() << hash;
   ```

Result:

> 098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6

---

2. If I use bash and mkpasswd:

   ```
   echo test | mkpasswd -s -5
   ```

Result:

> $1$xCs.somY$b/VXeBeO9DZbqCR/31iPT1

---

I need hash same as #2 result, but in Qt What am I doing wrong? I need hash of password in Qt.

Comment: What you are doing wrong? You are misunderstanding what mkpasswd does.

Comment: I need hash of password. It is possible to get result #2 in Qt?

Comment: It is absolutely possible. First step in that would be understanding what you need to do, so start by understanding what mkpasswd does to get that result.

Comment: Just an FYI - don't use md5 for password hashing - https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52461/how-weak-is-md5-as-a-password-hashing-function

Comment: The salt is randomly generated each time `mkpasswd` runs. So if you're attempting to get identical results - it's not going to happen. You can only get compatible results.

Comment: Your Qt5 code *is* giving the MD5 hash of the string "test" in hex encoding. Your mkpasswd command, on the other hand, is giving an MD5 hash of the string "test<newline>" *and a random salt value*, in base64 encoding, wrapped (along with the salt) in passwd entry format. Now: which of these do you actually want? **What are you actually trying to do?**

Comment: Depending on what you're actually trying to do, there are a number of possible answers *none of which match your question*. If you want the MD5 hash of a string, you want bash code that matches the Qt5 result, not vice versa. If you want to store a password hash, you should not use MD5 at all; use bcrypt or scrypt, or maybe Argon2 or PBKDF2. If you want to check against a stored password, you need to do something different from either of your code snippets, but closer to the mkpasswd command.

Comment: @GordonDavisson you are saying exactly what I was feeling, at work I would have filed this as **requirements unclear**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To replicate the behavior of `mkpasswd` using C++/Qt you need to figure out what it actually does. It does not hex encode the MD5 result of a string, what it does is more complex.

I started from the man page of [mkpasswd](https://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/mkpasswd/) and found that it is a frontend for [crypt](https://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/3/crypt/). So what does crypt do then?

Well the output is in the from of `$id$salt$encrypted` where id = 1 means MD5 then you have the salt which is combined with the input in some way finally there there is the output which is what comes from MD5 of the input+salt combo.

The alphabet used is almost base64 according to the manual, with `.` instead of `+`.

Answer (score 2):

You can replicate what you're doing in Qt issuing this bash command:

```
echo -n test  | md5sum
```

Notice the `-n` option, to suppress new line.

As far as I can see, `mkpasswd` is not intended to encrypt existing passwords, but to randomly generate new ones.

Comment: I'd recommend using `printf "%s"` instead of `echo -n` -- depending on a variety of factors, `echo -n test` might print "test" without a newline, or might print "-n test" *with* a newline.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand you want to generate a password hash for GNU/Linux.

Then you should check the format of the password stored in the /etc/shadow file. It is **not** simply an MD5 hash of the password.

The actual format is:

"$id$salt$hashed"

where:

- $id is the hashing algorithm. $1$ stands for MD5
- $salt is the random salt
- $hashed is the actual hash.

Have a look at the [crypt](https://linux.die.net/man/3/crypt) man page for more details.